# Does mongoose ODM autoload schemas/models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, schema, mongoose

If I define a nested model or a relation in a mongoose schema, does it have a mechanism to autoload everything when re-hydrating instances, or do I simply have to ensure I've always loaded the appropriate models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested, embedded model docs are auto-loaded, but if it's an `ObjectId` based relation, then you need to use Mongoose's [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) support to explicitly load the related docs.

Mongoose performs all these actions based on the schemas and models that your code defines, typically during your app's startup.

Comment: How does mongoose know which schema and model to use?  If I defined methods on it, would they still exist?

Comment: @Omega You do have to define all the schemas/models you want Mongoose to use.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: That's okay - I think my followup has clarified it.  If you want to update your answer, I'll mark it correct. :)